# On hover display:block

Tags: css

I want to display an item (container) when hovering on the a tag, like some sort of sub-menu. However I don't know why the CSS display rule doesn't seem to work.

```html
    <a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>
    
    <div>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>

    <style>

        div {display: none;}

        a:hover div {display: block;}
        .link:hover div {display: block !important;}

    </style>
```

Comment: You need a sibling selector, like `~` or `+`

Comment: There's no `div` that is a descendant of an `a`. That's what `a:hover div` says. You probably want `a:hover + div`. You want to read about [Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators).

Answer (score 0):

The [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) would work for this. When seperating selectors by the `+`, it matches the second selector only if it immediately follows the first selector.

Try adding `+` between your selectors such as:

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

a:hover div {
  display: block;
}

.link:hover + div {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">LINK</a>

<div>
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be useful if you explained what `+` is and how it works.